# Disable EXECUTE statement effect on CONTINUE HANDLER (mysql 5.5)

Tags: mysql, sql, mysql-5.5

I have a a sql code on mysql:

```sql
DELIMITER //
CREATE PROCEDURE proc()
main_block: BEGIN
 DECLARE is_finished BOOLEAN DEFAULT FALSE;
 DECLARE row_name VARCHAR(50) DEFAULT FALSE;
 DECLARE row_id INT DEFAULT FALSE;
 DECLARE cur CURSOR FOR SELECT `ID`, `Name` FROM `mytable`;
 DECLARE CONTINUE HANDLER FOR NOT FOUND SET is_finished = TRUE;

 OPEN cur;
 my_loop: REPEAT 
  FETCH cur INTO row_id, row_name;

  IF row_id IS NULL THEN
   LEAVE main_block;
  END IF;

  SET @query = concat('SELECT `ID` INTO @msg_id from ', row_name, '_msgs');
  PREPARE run_query FROM @query;
  EXECUTE run_query;
  DEALLOCATE PREPARE run_query;

  ...

 UNTIL is_finished
 END REPEAT my_loop;
 CLOSE cur;
END;
END //
```

`mytable` contains three rows so Repeat-Until should works three rounds, but after `EXECUTE run_query; DEALLOCATE PREPARE run_query;` `is_finished` gets `TRUE` and the loop ends after finishing first round.

How can I disable effect of `EXECUTE` on `is_finished` variable?

Comment: The first thing to determine is the cause that `is_finished` becomes `TRUE` in the first iteration. What returns `@query` in the first iteration?

Comment: `@query` doesn't care what is `is_finished` it returns true value. It affects on `is_finished` that Repeat-Until uses it.

Comment: That's right, but it seems that running the `EXECUTE` generates an error, which makes `is_finished` is `TRUE`, so it is important to know if `@query` is executed correctly.

Comment: Exactly after `DEALLOCATE PREPARE run_query;` I inserted the `@msg_id` into another table. It was correct value.

Comment: Perhaps the following [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/cd673/1) help us see the cause of the problem.